# How I can run javascript function in the data_bind = "checked" binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have radiobuttons with data_bind = "checked" binding. I need to call custom function to customize ui when one of the radiobuttons checked.
Html

Daily
        Weekly
        Monthly

```
<div data-bind="visible: FrequencyType() == 1">
    Message 1
</div>
<div data-bind="visible: FrequencyType() == 2">
    Message 2
</div>
<div data-bind="visible: FrequencyType() == 3">
    //Before show html here I want to call js function
</div>
```

js

```
    function AppViewModel() {
    this.FrequencyType = ko.observable("0");    
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    viewModel = new AppViewModel();

    // Activates knockout.js
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);   
});
```

[jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/TuBzb/2/)
How can I do it with knockout?

Comment: It is not really clear what js function do you want to call, and exactly when? When the `FrequencyType() == 3` or before the `visible` binding gets triggered?

Comment: After component will be visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a manual subscription on `FrequencyType`.

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/TuBzb/1/

```
this.FrequencyType.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    if (newValue == 3) {
        alert('3 is clicked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your problem but the jsFiddle example you provided does not work because the linked knockout library cannot be found. Here is a CDN link for knockoutjs and I updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TuBzb/2/)

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/1.2.1/knockout-min.js
```

In order to run a javascript function depending on a value is to subscribe to the ko.observable as documented [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html)